# I am trying to make a alarm like feature app but it keeps waiting

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to make a alarm like app where I want a list of things to happen when its time. But I am facing a bug. Time keeps waiting for previous time instead of going to next time in list.

```
t1 = dt.time(hour=17,minute=8)
t2 = dt.time(hour=18,minute=48)
timetable = [t1, t2]

for elt in timetable:
        i_time = elt
        #i_minute = i.minute
        while True:
            if i_time == dt.datetime.now().time():
            #if i_hour == dt.datetime.now().hour and i_minute == dt.datetime.now().minute:
                #current_time = tk.Label(text = dt.datetime.now())
                #current_time.pack()
                #playsound('media/ClassAlarm.mp3')
                print("Its time")
                break
```

The function works fine when it comes to t1 but if t1 is passed and current time is higher that t1 it should go to t2 and ring alarm. But it keeps waiting for t1 which will happen next day. it doesn't read t2 unless t1 is processed.

Ex. Current time 1:30 while t1 is 1:25 and t2 is 1:35. It doesn't ring at t2 but keeps waiting for t1 to happen again which has already happened.

I have tried to execute for loop in different way

```
for elt in timetable:
  time = dt.datetime.now().time()
  if time - elt < 0:
    break
  while(True):    
    if time == elt:
      print("you did it")
```

I have also tried `any()` method. Which isn't helping exactly as well

```
current_hour = dt.datetime.now().hour
current_min = dt.datetime.now().minute
alarm = any(i.hour == current_hour and i.minute == current_min for i in timetable)

print(alarm)
```

I have tried posting question previously but wasn't able to explain properly. Hope this helps

Comment: The next line after **while True:** can you change the comparison operator from **==** to **>=** and tell if that helps?

Comment: It doesn't help. It prints 'Its Time' without checking time.

Comment: Ohhh my bad, sorry change the sign to **<=** and tell again

Comment: I can't particularly spot any problems in your code

Comment: Thanks your option helped quite a lot. Comparison operator helps. Its just printing previous alarm as well which it shouldn't and only print next alarm

Comment: Hm so problem fixed or not? whats more to left

Comment: One problem solved. That even second time is playing but it is playing first time as well. then it waits for second time. So basically it should have ignored it completely and went to second time. If i set 5 action at 5 different time it executes all 5 actions

Comment: Okay I'm writing my answers with all relevants fixes of whatever you are asking, this was just logic problem,. You could always use if and else statements for different types..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using **==** Operator To Compare Time Is Risky, Logically It Should Work But Somehow It's Better To Use **<=** Operator Which Eventually Compare If Your Time Is Greater Than The One Recorded In List! This Is Lot Safer Than Equality Which Trigger Only Once And Has No Guarantee To Work For A Split

-->Note: I Believe Those Function Generated Timestamp Of Different Format, Although They Represent Time And Are Useful But Since They Are In Different Format You Ain't Getting Equality Operator To Work (Bcz Even for Same Time And Date, Your Timestamp Gonna Be Different Although They Represent Same). To confirm this behavior you can write print variables of **t1** and **datetime.now** and see if they are same.

*Regarding Your Second Question You Can Have *if/else* statements to check for which time has been occured and most last time which has just been crossed, or you can run loop in reverse and check for timer (assuming late timers are in end of loop)*

### Sample Code:

```
for elt in timetable.reverse():
    i_time = elt
    while True: 
        if i_time <= dt.datetime.now().time():
            print("Its time")
            break
```